# How to split (large) arrays like this?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to split this table (list/array)

```
fulltab={{{4,2},{7,0},{8,0},{9,0},{10,0},{11,0}},{{4,5},{10,0},{11,0},{12,0},{13,0},{14,0}},{{4,8},{10,3},{14,0},{15,0},{16,0},{17,0}},{{4,11},{10,6},{16,1},{18,0},{19,0},{20,0}},{{4,14},{10,9},{16,4},{21,0},{22,0},{23,0}},{{4,17},{10,12},{16,7},{23,1},{25,0},{26,0}},{{4,20},{10,15},{16,10},{23,4},{28,0},{29,0}}}
```

into

```
r={{4,7,8,9,10,11},{4,10,11,12,13,14},{4,10,14,15,16,17},{4,10,16,18,19,20},{4,10,16,21,22,23},{4,10,16,23,25,26},{4,10,16,23,28,29}}
```

and

```
d={{2,0,0,0,0,0},{5,0,0,0,0,0},{8,3,0,0,0,0},{11,6,1,0,0,0},{14,9,4,0,0,0},{17,12,7,1,0,0},{20,15,10,4,0,0}}
```

What's the most efficient way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: `r = fulltab[[All, All, 1]]`

Comment: `{r, d} = Transpose[fulltab, {2, 3, 1}]`

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Thanks! That's so easy!

Comment: @Kuba Thank you, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Transpose`:

```
{r, d} = Transpose[fulltab, {2, 3, 1}]
```